# QPixmaps Performance using Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpixmap

I am currently trying to create a game object that changes pixmap whenever it moves via `.setPos()` in a QGraphicsScene. Since I'm new to all this, I'm not sure what the most performance-efficient methods are to cache pixmaps or to change images. 
 
I've already looked at `QPixmapCache` and re-implementing the `paint()` function, but I'm still unsure what the best method is. This is the idea I've got at the moment:

```
class Object(QGraphicsPixmapItem):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Object, self).__init__()
        self.state = 0
        self.img = {
            "pix1": QPixmap("pix1.png"),
            "pix2": QPixmap("pix2.png"),
            "pix3": QPixmap("pix3.png")}

    def changePix(self):
        if self.state == 0:
            self.setPixmap(self.img["pix1"])
        elif self.state == 1:
            self.setPixmap(self.img["pix2"])
        elif self.state == 2:
            self.setPixmap(self.img["pix3"])
```

I would appreciate any advice or feedback I can get.

Comment: The images I'm using are all in the range of 400 - 800 bytes, but for some events I have to switch between images every 0.2 seconds or so.

Comment: QPixmap already uses QPixmapCache (when loaded from a file in the main thread): see [`QPixmap.load()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#load).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never had to use a `QPixmapCache` object to avoid any performance issue previously, but that's going to depend on what exactly you're doing. If you're just switching between 5 or so relatively small static/generated images (`.png < 20kB`), I would say it's not necessary. But if you're going to be doing something like a 2k paint buffer with an undo function, or some graph that would need to be regenerated after some paint event, you'll want some sort of caching in place. I refactored your code a bit as well to avoid hard-coding anything.

```
class Object(QGraphicsPixmapItem):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Object, self).__init__()
        self.img = [a for a in args if os.path.exists(a)]

    def load_image(img_path, set_now=False):
        if img_path not in self.img:
            self.img.append(img_path)
        if set_now:
             self.change_state(img_path)

    def change_state(img_path):
        if img_name in self.img:
            self.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.img[self.img.index(img_path)]))
```